facing issue 'resource not found' for asp .net 3.5 while running application on local machine
I am trying to compile old .net application on my local environment but it is showing 'Resource not found error' or Parser error.
.resx file is not available in the code but App_GlobalResources folder is present in the code.
I am getting two options once I right click on App_GlobalResources  folder publish or replace from server.
Is there any way  can retrieve this folder.
it is used in aspx file as follows
<asp:Label ID="MasterTitle" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: SampleData, MasterTitle %>"/>
I hardcoded the .resx and it is working as expected.
